# How to change jquery version used by helix3 template on Joomla site

Tags: jquery, helix, chronoforms, joomla3.8

I am building a Joomla (v3.8.13) website using the Shaper Helix3 template (v2.5.5). On this site I want to use Chronoforms v6 but I noticed that certain functionalities (validation error popups, tooltips, etc...) where not working when I activated the form on the site. However these functions where working in preview mode.

Now I noticed that during preview mode the page uses JQuery version 1.12.4. Which is the version provided by Joomla and can be found in the "/media/jui/js/" folder.
But on the site itself JQuery version 1.8 is used and is loaded directly from the repository. The line below is written between the head tags on the site.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now my best guess is that Helix3 somewhere overrides the Jquery version used and adds the link to the repository as shown above. But I can't figure out where and how. I have tried finding answers on several forums but all I found where methods to update the jquery version used by Joomla itself.

Other actions I have tried already are:

1. Re-installing Shaper-Helix3 template
2. Updating jquery.js and jquery.min.js of Joomla
3. Updating bootstrap.min.css for Helix3

Hopefully someone here can tell me how to fix this. Or at least point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The free or paid version of [jQuery Easy](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jquery-easy) is designed to solve this type of issue.

You can remove libraries that are being loaded, add libraries and specify the load order as required.

Comment: Thanks for the hint Neil. That works like a charm :)